# Cannot compile with waitid() and P_PID

Tags: c, waitpid

I am new to Linux. I am trying to use waitid() to wait for a child process.
When I try to compile a file including the following lines using gcc:

```
id_t cpid = fork();
siginfo_t status;
waitid(P_PID, cpid, &status, WEXITED);
```

The following error was generated:

```
error: ‘P_PID’ undeclared (first use in this function)
```

I included the following libraries:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h> 
#include <time.h>
```

Did I miss something?

Another question is that how can I use `WIFSIGNALED()` to retrieve information from type `siginfo_t`?

Comment: You might want to read a [`waitid` reference](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/waitid.html), you're not including the correct header file.

Comment: according to manual page of waitid(), the first argument of waitid() should be P_PID or P_ALL or P_GID , or did I misunderstand the usage of waitid()?

Comment: @user3545752: `#include <sys/wait.h>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include `<sys/wait.h>` and define `_XOPEN_SOURCE`, [as documented in the manual](http://linux.die.net/man/2/waitid).

The `WIFSIGNALED` macro must be used with the integer status obtained from `wait`, `waitpid` or `waitid`. In the case of `waitpid`, the status is available as the `si_status` member of the `siginfo_t` structure. In other words, you would use `WIFSIGNALED(info.si_status)`, `info` being a structure of type `siginfo_t` whose address you previously passed to `waitid()`.

Comment: Thx! I didn't realize that I didn't include <sys/wait.h>